# How to display mysql Json data

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I've a table in database call purchase. Where i insert few data as a JOSN format. In that json formate there are multiple data stored. exp- "products" has 2 data

[image: Database Table Image]

```
[{"products":["Asulak Silver 7","Print Gum MAP NEW"]},{"qnt":["2","1"]},{"unit_price":["1500","600"]},{"pack_size":["60","60"]},{"unit_pack":["2","1"]},{"packing":["Dram","Jar"]},{"total_kg":["120","60"]},{"total_price":["3000","600"]}]
```

I've use the `json_decode()` function and i get this-

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Asulak Silver 7
                    [1] => Print Gum MAP NEW
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qnt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [unit_price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1500
                    [1] => 600
                )

        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pack_size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 60
                    [1] => 60
                )

        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [unit_pack] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [packing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Dram
                    [1] => Jar
                )

        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total_kg] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 120
                    [1] => 60
                )

        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total_price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3000
                    [1] => 600
                )

        )

)
```

But i don't know how to display in my view table like this - [image]

I'm  new in Codeigniter. Please help me Thank You in advance.

I have use this code

```
$json = array(  array('products' => $products), 
                array('qnt' => $qnt), 
                array('unit_price' => $unit_price), 
                array('pack_size' => $pack_size), 
                array('unit_pack' => $unit_pack), 
                array('packing' => $packing), 
                array('total_kg' => $total_kg), 
                array('total_price' => $total_price) 
            ); 
$json_type = json_encode($json); //Sending arrays into json
```

Comment: Looks like data that shouldn't have been in JSON in the first place

Comment: i use this code - $json = array(
            array('products' => $products),
            array('qnt' => $qnt),
            array('unit_price' => $unit_price),
            array('pack_size' => $pack_size),
            array('unit_pack' => $unit_pack),
            array('packing' => $packing),
            array('total_kg' => $total_kg),
            array('total_price' => $total_price)
        );

        $json_type = json_encode($json); //Sending arrays into json

Comment: Well you have an array of Objects. All you need to do is write a loop. So whats the problem

Comment: Nobody can read code in a comment. Edit your question to add more information next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User this code for array re-range:

```
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
$data=array();
foreach($array as $value){
    foreach($value as $key=>$value){
    }
    $data[$key]=$value;
}
```

And for view use this code:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Product Name</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>unit_price</td>
<td>pack_size</td>
<td>unit_pack</td>
<td>packing</td>
<td>total_kg</td>
<td>total_price</td>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($data['products'] as $k=>$v){?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['qnt'][$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['unit_price'][$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['pack_size'][$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['unit_pack'][$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['packing'][$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['total_kg'][$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['total_price'][$k]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help (y)

Comment: @MarufAhmed Welcome